# Is a Fabric Module required for a Nexus 7009, or is it part of the Chassis?

Tags: networking, cisco, local-area-network, switch, cisco-nexus

I noticed that Cisco lists separate fabric modules for the Nexus 7009 switch.  If I were to simply buy the Nexus 7009 Chassis (N7K-7009), what would I need at minimum?  I just want to confirm, but I would guess:

```
1) At least one Supervisor module (N7K-SUPx)
2) At least one Fabric Module? (Are redundant fabric modules recommended)
3) At least one IO line card
4) Power supplies
```

I am not sure if the IO line cards such as the (N7K-M224XP-23L) negate the need for a fabric module such as the N7K-FAB2=.  Anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your guess is overall good, but I think the minimum fabric modules is 3. I believe the system needs at least 2, so having 3 leaves room for one to fail. I don't think you really have to have a line card, but you can't do much with it if you don't have at least one.

The I/O cards just give you your interfaces. The switch fabric requires the fabric modules.

Your Cisco rep or your VAR should be able to help you understand this better. I can also recommend checking out some technical training for the Nexus 7000 available on ciscolive365.com (free account required), such as this session: https://www.ciscolive365.com/connect/sessionDetail.ww?SESSION_ID=4136